# DataFrame groupby on sequence of values not exceeding threshold

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame with two columns.

```
data=DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1,4,1,1,3,1,4,1,1,1],'b':[5,2,8,3,10,3,5,15,45,41,23,9]}) 

    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   2
2   1   8
3   4   3
4   1   10
5   1   3
6   3   5
7   1   15
8   4   45
9   1   41
10  1   23
11  1   9
```

I want to partition the DataFrame into groups based on the value of Column 'a' exceeding a given threshold. in this case the threshold is 3, so I want a new group whenever column 'a' exceeds the value of 3.

I want my groups to look like this

```
    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   2
2   1   8


    a   b
0   4   3
1   1   10
2   1   3
3   3   5
4   1   15

    a   b
0   4   45
1   1   41
2   1   23
3   1   9
```

The only thing I can think of is applying cummax

```
data['max']=data.b.cummax()
```

but his will only works in limited situations where the values greater than 3 are always getting bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(data.a > 3).cumsum`; This creates the desired group variable you need:

```
threshold = 3
for k, g in data.groupby((data.a > threshold).cumsum()):
    print(g, "\n")

#   a  b
#0  1  5
#1  2  2
#2  1  8 

#   a   b
#3  4   3
#4  1  10
#5  1   3
#6  3   5
#7  1  15 

#    a   b
#8   4  45
#9   1  41
#10  1  23
#11  1   9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MultiIndex based on the values of `a` and apply it to the data frame.  This will allow you to perform slicing operations on the data later.

There may be a faster way to do this, but you can create a boolean series of each time `a` is greater than a threshold (in this case 3), use `cumsum` to create an index for each group, count the occurrences in each group, and use that count to create an additional level to the index.

```
new_index = ((data.a>3).cumsum().value_counts(sort=False)
                       .apply(range).apply(pd.Series).stack().index)
data2 = data.set_index(new_index)
data2

# returns:
     a   b
0 0  1   5
  1  2   2
  2  1   8
1 0  4   3
  1  1  10
  2  1   3
  3  3   5
  4  1  15
2 0  4  45
  1  1  41
  2  1  23
  3  1   9
```

This allows you to access each of the desired groups by calling the first index.

```
data2.loc[0]

# returns:
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  2
2  1  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

I:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(a)
```

O:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6]])
```

I:

```
np.cumsum(a)
```

O:

```
array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21])
```